# autocomplete input fields - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two inputs `name` and `phone` inputs. When I type a phone number, the name of the of the client should appear in the name input box.

With my code below, what happens is, when i start typing a new number which doesn't exist, the query selects the name of a person whose number is similar. Why is this happening?

What I want is, if the number doesn't exist, the query should not populate my name textbox.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Phone</label>

    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input type="text" class="typeahead form-control" id="phone" placeholder=" Customer Phone Number" autocomplete="on" name="phone" required>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-lg-1 control-label"> Name</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder=" Customer Name" name="name" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function autocomplete(AutoCompleteFormRequest  $request)
{
    $query = $request->get('query','');        
    $client = Client::where('phone','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')->get();        
    return response()->json($customer);       
}
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

    var path = "{{ route('autocomplete') }}";
    var obj;
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        source: function (query,process){
            return $.get(path, {query:query},function (data)
            {
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    obj = data[i];                 
                    $("#name").val(obj.name);
                }
                return process(data);    
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Because that's what you seem to be doing inside the controller. Loose the '%'s and it should work as you want.

Comment: hey can you mark the answer as correct if it worked for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because you are using `LIKE` statement for finding phone numbers

`Client::where('phone','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')->get();`

if you need to show the names of the users who have the exact same match of the number change the above line to

`Client::where('phone','=',$query)->get();`

or

`Client::where('phone','LIKE',$query)->get();`

**EDIT:**

Additionally if you want the name to be cleared from the `name` input if there are no results returned in the response you should add the following inside the `$.get` change it to look like following.

```
return $.get(path, {
    query: query
}, function (data) {

    (data.length == 0) ? $("#name").val(''): '';
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        obj = data[i];
        $("#name").val(obj.name);
    }
    return process(data);
})
```

This line `(data.length==0)?$("#name").val(''):'';` will track if there are no results returned from the response it will clear out the value in the `name` input box

Comment: now when i clear the phone input box, the name input still remains. when i begin clearing the phone input box, the name should clear out

Comment: what do you mean by **name input still remains** which name are you talking about and which of the above solution are you using `LIKE` or `=`

Comment: i am using `Client::where('phone','LIKE',$query)->get();`  When i type in a number, the name shows now. But when i start clearing the phone number, the name in the name input must also clear out

Comment: ahh you mean the other input name, let me update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try not using the first '%', that way it'll match the beginning portion of the number without trying to match within